# Improper integrals and convergence

Tags: real-analysis, integration, convergence-divergence

Let C= {(x,y) such that  x>0, y> 0}. Let f(x,y) = $\frac{1}{(x^2 +\sqrt x )(y^2 + \sqrt y)}$
Show that $\int_C{f}$ exists, do not attempt to calculate it. 
Attempt at at solution:
I was thinking that since f(x,y) $\leq (xy)^{-\frac{1}{2}}$ we can use pointwise estimate if we show that $(xy)^{-\frac{1}{2}}$ is convergent, it is convergent on [0,1]^2 but I can't show that it is convergent on [1, $\infty$]
Please help and be as detailed as possible, and if you have a different method I would love to see that too. 
Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hints: 1. Verify that $\int_0^\infty 1/(\sqrt t + t^2)\,dt < \infty.$

2. Because $f(x,y) \le (1/\sqrt x)(1/(\sqrt y +y),$ you can use 1) to see

$$\int_0^1\int_0^\infty f(x,y)\,dydx <\infty.$$

Same thing for $\int_0^1\int_0^\infty f(x,y)\,dxdy.$

3. So you'll be done if you show $\int_1^\infty\int_1^\infty f(x,y)\,dxdy < \infty.$

Comment: I was stuck on this for the longest time. Thank you so much, you are actually awesome !!!